# How to get Task Due date of Custom object in email template?

Tags: salesforce

I have a custom object and that has Task(s), I want to get the due date of the task to be included in the email (template) I plan to send out. Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the work. Just replace "Custom_Object_Name" with the actual name and Task__r withe relationship name.

```
 {!Custom_Object_Name__c.Task__r.ActivityDate}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However it didn't work. it showed an error  Error: Unknown property 'core.email.template.EmailTemplateComponentController.MyObject__c'

Comment: OK this Email Template have to be connected to Workflow Rule for Salesforce to know from which object (table row in DB terminology) take values.